# android - flash live stream in application using webview or videoview

Tags: android, webview, android-videoview, live-streaming

I'm trying to make an app which plays a live stream inside the android app.

The source path is:

```
"http://mediasuite.316networks.com/templates/livefull2.swf"
```

which is a flash file, played with adobe flash player.

I've had a look at both `VideoView` and `WebView`.

So i have a few questions:

1)
Assuming that adobe flash is installed on the android device (and yes the stream can be played via a browser), how can I play this live video stream inside the app?

2)
Using `VideoView`, i have managed to get youtube videos playing with the `MediaController`.
But is there a way to do this with a live stream that requires flash?

3)
Finally, in my situation, which view should I be using to get this flash live stream video played in the application? and how?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use webview, set the content of webview your flash file, set browser settings as needed (fullscreen, plugins enabled)

Dont forget to add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://mediasuite.316networks.com/templates/livefull2.swf");




        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Is Deprecated from API Level 18. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362049/setpluginsenabled-not-exist-for-webview) for more info.

Even I am searching how to View flash content using VideoView or WebView. I tried PhoneGap also but no luck.