# Android webview setPluginsEnabled api

Tags: android, webview

I have been using WebView.setPluginsEnabled() and targetSdkVersion 17 in my app(already in playstore). Now, I am about to release it's updated version with some new features. I have set the targetSdkVersion 19 but I have compiled it successfully with android build target 4.2.2. I have verified on various versions and the build runs fine. Is there any case or concern in releasing this build ?

I have already referred the following link:
[setPluginsEnabled not exist for WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362049/setpluginsenabled-not-exist-for-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in version 19 (4.4 - Kit Kat), Web Views have been updated to use chrome for their base. This can have different behavior to the old style webview. So you should test with a 4.4 device (or emulator...).

So anything below 19 uses the old webview and 19 and above uses the chrome based webview

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

Comment: Yes, that's right but I have already verified on 4.4 and older versions like 4.2, 4.0 and the build runs fine.
My main concern is that **if I compile build against android build target 4.4 when targetSdkVersion is set 19, then it gives error at line WebView.setPluginsEnabled() as it has been removed. But the same works fine when android build target is android 4.2**

Comment: If you read the documentation then you will see WebView. setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON) will still work in current version but is now depreciated so in a future version of android it will be removed and then your webview will not work on any device running that version. Look here to see what targetSdkVersion actually means http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

Comment: It's true that when targetSdkVersion is set to 19 then I have to compile build using target 4.4 to debug the errors caused due to removal(not deprecation) of some api like **setPuginsEnabled**. I got the expected error on the line WebView.setPluginsEnabled() when I try to compile the build using target 4.4. But when the build is compiled with target 4.2 no error is produced and it compiled successfully, also it runs fine(without any crash) on various versions. So here is my concern: Should I release this build or is there something else I should take care of ?

Comment: I would release the build