# How to enable webview in androidstudio

Tags: android, html

I am trying to load an animated html file to draw arc and line. Please let me know how to enable javascript in android studio. Button click it should call the html file to draw arc or line. But it is simply viewing like text, Its not drawing. Please tell me how to call html canvas files in android studio.

I tried the following code to load my html file

```
   `WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser1);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
```

But in android studio it is showing like **cannot resolve method setPluginsEnabled(boolean).**

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362049/setpluginsenabled-not-exist-for-webview

Comment: I checked that link also. And i tried using WebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); It is showing **This Inspection reports where deprecate code is used in the specified inspection scope**

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Tells the **WebView** to enable *`JavaScript`* execution. The default is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.setFocusable(true);
    myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview)

**see this link**

Comment: Thanks amit. This is not showing any errors. Still the animation is not running. If possible can u post some sample code which works fine.

Comment: see this all full  code http://techminders.blogspot.in/2015/07/webview-for-beginner-in-android-with.html

Comment: Is the above code is just to call webpage? I am trying to draw a line by giving points. Starting point and ending point, I am trying to draw a line by giving these two points using html.  I want to call the following like html file http://jsfiddle.net/UtmTh/